Replacing two large gears with (hopefully 3) smaller gears
I have computed that the gear ratio I need can be achieved with a 183 toothed gear driving a 365 toothed gear (this is for a sidereal clock).  The problem is those are quite large, with the module 1, 365 toothed gear being about 16" in diameter.  So I'm looking for a way replace the large gears with smaller ones, and keep the same gear ratio.
I assume this is a pretty common problem, but have been unable to find any references.  Everything I've found is essentially the reverse problem (computing the ratio given the gear sizes).  Through a lot of guesswork, I have come up with the solution below, which I'm not really sure if it's correct.  Also, I would hope there's a way to reduce the number of gears to 3 by combining the two intermediate gears (to reduce complexity, and get the output spinning the right way).
The below diagram is what I have come up with, and my hope is that it is equivalent to the 183:365.  The input is on the left with 61 teeth, driving a 10 tooth axially attached to a 30 tooth, which drives a 73 tooth axially attached to a 15 tooth, which drives the 75 tooth output.


The ratio you have is correct.

To maintain the direction of rotation you need an even number of axles. With two axles your gears are too big - you're stuck with four axles. So your set up is probably as simple as any.  You could use three axles with an idler wheel on the fourth axle, for example 61 drives 50 with coaxial 30 drives 73 plus idler to reverse direction. If the idler is an intermediate gear it can be any size, if it's an end gear has to be same size as it is driven.

Unfortunately you have two large prime numbers in there - so not many choices.

@Rich, thanks.  I actually want to reverse the rotation from how it is now, so an odd number would be preferable, I guess I didn't explain that part well enough.

Don't forget to consider forces throughout your system. Larger usually means more material to distribute loads over so going small tends to concentrate stresses.

@Abel, thanks. This is for a clock, so just 2 revs per day and not much force.

SO your answer is what I suggested; 61 gear wheel drives 50 with coaxial 30 drives 73. That will give you 183:365.

@Rich, thanks.  Can you explain how you figured that out (in an answer), or point me to some reference that explains it?

The ratio $\frac{183}{365}$ can be factored to $\frac{61*3}{73*5}$. This ratio for gears is better as $\frac{61*30}{73*50}$ as gears with three cogs just aren't going to make it. This can be rewritten as $\frac{61}{50}*\frac{30}{73}$ So then you have 61 drives 50 and 30 drives 73. Put the 50 and 30 gears on the same axle and you're done.
61 gear wheel drives 50 with coaxial 30 drives 73. That will give you 183:365.

How did you calculate the ratio you needed 183:365 for you sidereal clock?
